# Interactive checkbox filter for ggvis plot

Tags: r, plot, statistics, ggvis

I currently have some data for which I'd love to be able to add an interactive multiple checkbox option that lets the user select which area of the body they want to view data from. At the moment it looks like this:

```
library(ggvis)
areas_data %>%
ggvis(~Bacilli, ~Actinobacteria) %>%
filter(area %in% c("Skin", "Oral", "Gut") ) %>%
layer_points( fill = ~area, size := 50, opacity := 0.5)
```

I can't figure out how to change the filter line so that it will interactively change the data you're viewing. I've tried inserting input_checkboxgroup into the filter line, but keep receiving an error about how the comparison is only possible for atomic and list types. I've tried a lot of different variants of the line, an example being:

```
filter(area %in% input_checkboxgroup(c("Skin" = "Skin", "Oral" = "Oral", "Gut" = "Gut") ) ) %>%
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your question to include `library` calls for all the non-default packages you are using. (And that last line looks incomplete.)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include the library call to ggvis. The last line was an example of what I'd been substituting within the filter section of the previous code which wasn't working.

Comment: I asked to see the `library`-call since I thought the `%>%` was from another package,  but it seems to be a graphics operator (as well as a data operator). Not much more we can do to help since the `areas_data`-object is not part of the examples in that package.

Comment: Its a new operator that's been brought in for some of the new R packages. I tried asking the question on stack because I was hoping someone with ggvis experience would be able to confirm whether what I was trying with the package was feasible.

Answer (score 1):

This same question was asked and fully answered over in the ggvis google discussion group (basically, you need to use 'eval' inside the 'filter' call).

Posting the link to the answer (from the person who wrote the R package no less) here for future reference:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggvis/AJZCdjFcNaE

Comment: That was me, I ended up asking it there a while after asking here when no-one had answered. Thanks tho :)